# Printing a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a small program to store and hopefully print contact information (in vb.net). The program contains a few text fields and a picture box. Saves the Information and so on. Can anyone recommend a quick way to save the form to a format that can then be transferred to her work computer and printed (she can't install my program at work, taboo policy and so on). Using the printform control, printform.print() with the PrintAction set to PrintToFile is just giving me garbled junk. I guess I could print to an html file bit by bit, but I thought I'd ask if anyone knows a better way. Also, with the html route I'm not sure how I'd add the contents of the picture box. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you could always write to a text file and send it or HTML would work to, but you mention an image so my guess would be to an HTML file and then again you would have to send the images as well. Another option is to create an email and send it...

Comment: Thanks, That will be good practice anyway. Will I have to save the contents of the imagebox to a file then reference the image name and location in the markup? I'm not sure I could formatt the e-mail correctly (I want the printable version in a format like a card for a rolladex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try saving your Form to a Bitmap using the [DrawToBitmap Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which could then be saved as an image then printed out later, the main problem you will run into with this method is that the DPI settings are different between the screen and a printer.

```
Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
Me.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), Me.Size))
bmp.Save("C:\temp\123.bmp") 'Set your path and your filename here
```

Comment: That sounds great. I'll give it a try. Didn't know that was possible and its a good thing to know. Thanks.

Comment: Your are welcome, I am saving the full form in this example this method is available for Controls also, so for instance if you put a panel on your form then put your other controls in that, you could then save the panel's content as a bitmap eliminating the Window chrome that my example has.

Comment: +1 good answer, I'm not sure whats behind the lack of upvotes in recent days.

Comment: It was exactly what I wanted. Works like a charm and circumvents our printer problems. The point about calling the method with other controls is well taken also. I can't upvote yet but the response is much appreciated.

Comment: @user1975195 You may not be able to upvote yet, but you can click the Checkmark to the left of the answer to mark your question as answered. You will get some reputation also.